# Perform actions once anchor element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am having a webpage load another webpage inside an iframe that takes up the entire screen. I have 2 div's that are on top of each other. These divs are actually anchors that direct to a new url (an action). What I am trying to do is once any of the divs is clicked, to initiate an onclick event that will go to the url specified in that anchor href, and then reload the initial index.html page. My class is working on a local enviroment to teach us a thing called clickjacking. Below is my current html.

The issue im having is I can have the anchor click go to the url I want, but then I am no longer in my index.html. Is it possible to open the referenced link in a new window, close the new window once its loaded and then refresh the index.html page. Once that is done to hide the div that was clicked since the "second" div is hidden behind the top most clickable div.

```
<html> 
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
<!-- Two anchor divs that are clickable and on top of each other -->  
        <div id="secondDiv">
            <a href="http://www.2ndURL.com" id="m2">
                <div id="2" style="position:absolute;top:195px;left:10px;width:10000px;height:200px;">
                    <iframe>
                    </iframe>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="firstDiv">
            <a href="#" id="m1" onclick="myFunction(); return false;">
                <div id="1" style="position:absolute;top:195px;left:10px;width:10000px;height:200px;">
                    <iframe>
                    </iframe>
                </div>
            </a>
<!-- Main iFrame where user interacts -->
        </div>
        <iframe id="new" src="http://www.mywebpage.com" style="opacity:1.0;width:100%;height:100%;">
        </iframe> 
    </center> 
</body> 
<script>
function myFunction(){
    var newWindow = window.open("http://www.actionURL");
    newWindow.close()
    var myWindow = window.open("file:///home/seed/Desktop/index.html", "_self");

}
</script>
</script>
</html>
```

TLDR:

- Load iframe in webpage
- click on anchor div on page that directs to a new url
- load that url, once loaded go back to the index.html (all in one tab) (step 1)
- hide the anchor div that was selected-- allowing second anchor to be
  clicked

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might need to "fake" the onclick if you want to have an onclick action work on the page you are on. You will need to modify the parameters, but here is a code that I have used:

```
    $(function() {
    // find out what our query parameters contain.
    var query = location.search;

    // isolate the position of the equal sign.
    var equalIndex = query.indexOf('=');
    // extract the image's id.
    var imageId = query.substring(equalIndex + 1);

    // click on the appropriate image.
    $('#' + imageId).click();
    });
```

The comments explain what each step of the code performs. In my case, I needed the page to load and then force the onclick using the unique image ids. In your case, you will need to tie it to your unique div. I hope that this helps you get started.

Comment: not sure if I follow. The user (myself) will click in a region where the anchor div is sitting (clear box). I am able to make it click and run an action, but the only issue is it loads the actual url. I need it to load a url that contains parameters (submit changes) and then reload the index.html to update the ui to the user, and still allowing the hidden clickable box to be active (so the user ends up doing the action for me again). Remember I am the user emulating a clickjacking attempt.

Comment: The way I understood it was that the user does the initial click that runs an action but you need it to do a second action (submit changes) and reload the index.html page. My thought was that after the user did the initial click, you could do the second .click() to complete the second action and reload the index.html. I am using the .click() to perform a second action of opening a hidden div after the user has clicked on a menu item. I thought the processes paralleled and that it might work for you.